# Go through items in a composer legend (QGIS 2.6)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, legend, print-composer

I'm trying to develop a plugin in QGIS 2.6, which opens a composer, add a map and a legend, and (among other things) adjusts the legend.

Is there a way to go through items in a composer legend with PyQgis?
What I'd want in the end is to change the item name, depending on the type of item (group, raster ...).

Here is my code:

```
for legend in self.composition.items():
    if isinstance(i,QgsComposerLegend):
        legend.setAutoUpdateModel(True)
        legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)            
        for item in legend.items():
            if item.itemtype() == QgsComposerLegendItem.GroupItem:
                groupItem.setUserText() = 'another text'
```

Qgis answers that QgsComposerLegend has not attribute called "items" (which I expected).
I looked for a property to iterate on legend items, and I have not found it in the API documentation nor in web searches.

Answer (score 6):

Finally I found the answer : using the QgsLegendModelV2()class, and its functions inherited from QgsLayerTreeModel : "index(i,j)" to select each legend item and "rowcount" to obtain the rows number. All in a "for x in xrange" loop.

That gives:

```
for i in self.composition.items():
    if isinstance(i,QgsComposerLegend):
        legend = i
        for i in xrange(legend.modelV2().rowCount()):
            posteleg=legend.modelV2().index(i, 0)
            print posteleg.data()
```

Best regards

Comment: This way you get the item name. But how do you change it?