# Changing legend item text with pyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, python-2.7, legend

Using code I found at [Go through items in a composer legend (QGIS 2.6)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138437) I can access the  the layers in my legend fine. However, I have layers that are styled by category and I can't figure out how to change the category labels. I just want to replace the underscores in the category labels with a space.

After looking through the API I think I may be able to use the rendererV2 class. The code below is giving strange results. the first set of `print` commands return 'foo', but the second set return the original labels and these are also printed on the output pdf.

Is there something I'm missing with the renderer? or, is there a better way to achieve this task?

I'm using QGIS 2.18.7 on windows 8

```
    for legendLyr in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        if legendLyr.name() != "os1250_line" and legendLyr.name() != "os1250_text":
            renderer = legendLyr.rendererV2()
            if renderer.type() == "categorizedSymbol":
                myRenderer = renderer.clone()
                for cat in myRenderer.categories():
                    cat.setLabel("foo")
                    print(cat.label())
                legendLyr.setRendererV2(myRenderer)
                for cat in legendLyr.rendererV2().categories():
                    print (cat.label())
                legendLyr.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need use [updateCategoryLabel()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer.html#ae9ef7faf97240ff808219b514c699e41) method for update the label.

Example Code:

```
for legendLyr in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
if legendLyr.name() != "os1250_line" and legendLyr.name() != "os1250_text":
    renderer = legendLyr.rendererV2()
    if renderer.type() == "categorizedSymbol":
        myRenderer = renderer.clone()
        idx=0
        for cat in myRenderer.categories():
            myRenderer.updateCategoryLabel (idx,"foo")
            idx+=1      
        legendLyr.setRendererV2(myRenderer)
        legendLyr.triggerRepaint()
```

And the result is:

[image]

***Tested QGIS 2.18.13 and W10***